# How can I make spring security accept csrf tokens that are sent via json. It's currently working via multipart/form-data but not application/json

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

I believe the issue lies in the spring security module not being setup by default to parse json input. Issue is i have no clue where to look as i've been duckduckgo-ing this problem on and off for the last couple weeks to no avail. This is specifically for the logout button. It requires a form submission to logout and the form submission requires the csrf token. The form will submit and logout successfully if the enctype is multipart/formdata but fails on any other type. The request is being sent via fetch. The return status code is 403 forbidden as it would be if there was a csrf issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks
Joseph

I have tried to use https://ckinan.com/blog/spring-security-credentials-from-json-request/ but it wasn't what I needed. It let me change the credentials into json but I don't believe it's what i need unless i'm thinking of this wrong and there is a way I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to add the csrf token to the header instead of the body with the name X-CSRF-TOKEN